# $\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(t)^pd\lambda_n(t)=p\int_{(0,+\infty)}t^{p-1}.\lambda_n(\{x \in \mathbb R^n:f(x)>t\})d\lambda(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to [0,+\infty]$ be measurable and $p>0$. How can I use Fubini to show that

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(t)^pd\lambda_n(t)=p\int_{(0,+\infty)}t^{p-1}.\lambda_n(\{x \in \mathbb R^n:f(x)>t\})d\lambda(t)$$

I tried working with $f(x)^p=\int_{0}^{f(x)}pt^{p-1}dt=\int_{0}^{+\infty}pt^{p-1}1_{(0,f(x))}(t)dt$ but I dont know how to continue.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309163/integration-with-respect-to-distribution-function-in-steins-book/2309234

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: @hal4math Yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does just come from Fubini's theorem. If we call $\lambda^f(t)=\lambda_n(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)|>t\}),$ then the calculation is 
\begin{align*}
\|{f}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}^p&=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int\limits_0^{|f(x)|}pt^{p-1}\ dtdx\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\left(\int\limits_{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\ |f(x)|>t>0\}}\ dx\right)\ dt\\
&= \int\limits_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\lambda^f(t)\ dt,
\end{align*}
where Fubini's theorem is used on the second equality. It might take a bit of thinking to see why Fubini's theorem acts in this way, of course.